# Tensorflow C API Multithreading, which is correct

Tags: c, tensorflow

Option 1:
`TF_Graph* graph` and `TF_SessionWithGraph* session` is created in the main thread.
multiple threads call `TF_SessionRun` with graph and session from main thread and with thread local `TF_Tensor`.

Option 2:
`TF_Graph* graph` is initialized in the main thread.
multiple `TF_SessionWithGraph` is created in worker threads using the same graph initialized in the main thread. `TF_SessionRun` is called with graph from the main thread with thread local `TF_Tensor`.

Option 3:
Both `TF_Graph` and `TF_SessionWithGraph` are thread local.

Comment: Haven't experimented with C++ interface, but if it's similar to Python version, all 3 approaches are valid. The first approach allows for reuse of Session/Graph objects between threads so it's most memory efficient

Comment: In many of the docs, it says session is thread safe, so multi threads can use the same session to achieve parallelism. I understand it as multiple sessions can run different part of the graph cocurrently. What if I use this mechanism just to calculate different data from different users? It means there are multiple copies of intermediate tensor attached to the graph?